# Difference between SynEdit and TurboPack SynEdit?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, synedit

What is the difference between SynEdit and TurboPack SynEdit?

TurboPack is available to install in Delphi 11. There is no documentation available on GitHub profiles, so I need your support to learn more about this.

Comment: Which is the 1st SynEdit that you are referring to? It would help if you would explain what you are looking at so people know what you are trying to compare TurboPack to.

Comment: Since SynEdit moved to Github, there are now so many SynEdit projects that it's difficult to find out which ones are more than personal forks. There are at least 3 major ones: SynEdit/SynEdit, TurboPack/SynEdit and pyscripter/SynEdit. They have apparently been forked from each other in that order.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: TurboPack SynEdit was a commecial product developed by TurboPower. When TurboPower was acquired by another company and stopped developing components for Delphi, they made it open source. SynEdit is a different open source project which does the same thing (provide a syntax-formatting text editor), but supports many more languages than Delphi.